# push an answer as comment to question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Often when checking the low quality posts we come across answers which should have been comment on another answer or the question or just link in answer, and we flag them so.

As the end of flag votes, usually in the link only answer and commentary on post cases we delete the answer altogether.

I propose that we get an option to push it as a comment on the question, especially if it is flagged as link only answer so that the usefulness of the answer, however small, remains.
[image]

Comment: While I do support the spirit of that request, how do you propose to handle content beyond 600 characters, what should be done with unsupported markup (blockquote, for example), and what about users who don't yet have the ability to comment everywhere?

Comment: As far as I've seen, any time I've seen one of these cases where an answer should have been a comment, but is in-depth enough to include unsupported markup or is long enough to exceed 600 chars, it falls into one of three categories: (1) could potentially be developed into an answer/needs editing to remove off-topic crap, (2) not related to the topic at hand, or (3) spam. I still think this is a good idea, since each of these three categories have alternate means of being handled already.

Comment: A good intention, but I could see this turn into *"I don't have enough rep to comment, someone convert this pls? Anyway, on with my non-answer..."*

Comment: @4444 I see this being most useful in the case of users who have enough rep to comment, but no will to do so.

Comment: @4444 except people already do that *plus* who does that doesn't usually know how things work so the chances that he is aware of this feature are zero. Generally people that take the time looking at all features like this *does* have the reputation to at least comment.

Comment: how tough is it to add a condition to push it as comment IF he has that reputation, ELSE the AS-IS removal....?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an interesting and creative idea.  I see a few potential hang-ups, however:

- For comments on another post, we don't know which post it's a comment for.  Sometimes the answers are "that answer didn't work for me," so that's a potential problem.
- What about link-only answers that *might* be spam?  Will there be a separate option for that?  Otherwise I could see more spam sneaking into comments.
- "Answers" that are overly long comments (over 600 characters) won't be able to be auto converted.
- Comments don't support as much formatting.

So while your idea seems ok at first glance, I have some reservations on how this is all accomplished.  Besides, comments are supposed to be even more prone to deletion than answers, so the useful content might very well disappear anyway.

Comment: Also, too many will use the "more lenient" option of converting to comment instead of deleting outright where appropriate. And reviewers are *not* proxies for circumventing restrictions.

Comment: If the answer is link only **and** spam then it should be flag spam not a link only answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to address what I think are two somewhat different issues.

### General feature of pushing answers into comments

If the content is well formed enough to be preserved somewhere, then the reviewer needs to determine where it goes and put it there. In most cases, this would mean one of:

- Editing the content into the question as a clarification
- Editing the content into another answer as a clarification
- Posting your own comment restating the point/question/concern on the appropriate post

The former two are preferable when the content is solid enough to warrant it. Attribution to the original poster is appropriate in all cases. Note that if you can't figure out which post it belongs with, then it's not well formed enough to preserve.

Doing this manually avoids the fiddly problems mentioned by other users; you as a person doing it have the ability to apply your judgement in solving problems with formatting and length. As long as you attribute it and preserve the essence of the post you're deleting (and *don't* include problematic portions), I can't see any problem with doing this.

There is a sort of problem here that requiring the work be done manually doesn't solve that you may be hoping to solve with this feature: it's not easy and so users will sometimes forego doing this work in favor of just deleting and moving on. I contend that these users shouldn't be trying to convert the content into a comment, anyway, since they are not willing to put forth the effort to determine the right course of action.

### Link only answers

These shouldn't be converted into comments. If the link is a valuable resource, just edit the answer to incorporate some of the link's relevant content or explain in detail how the resource is helpful. Then it becomes a good answer and you can choose not to delete it. If link doesn't contain any good content, just delete and move on.

### Conclusion

Proper reviewing is hard work, especially in the LQ queue. It's extremely uncommon that the best course of action is to simply click a button and move on. Usually, additional research is required, and often, some sort of work needs to be done outside of the queue to put things right. If you're not regularly opening questions outside the queue to look through them and get context before you make a determination anyway, you're probably doing it wrong.